# When running "./gradlew <task>" in command line, what file is read?

Tags: java, gradle, command-line, build.gradle, gradlew

I have done some digging, but have not found much information.

My best guess would be the `build.gradle` file is the default, but I was curious on the behavior and what files are read.

Comment: On Linux you can find out with [`strace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace). Call for example `strace -f -o strace.log ./gradlew clean`. Then scan the log for `open`.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch, lol, that is _the most complete_ answer on this question, indeed!

Comment: Could you please accept [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232139/542270) answer instead of mine, it's far much better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the other answer covers 99.99% of all builds, it is not complete.

The full command is `./gradlew [-b / --build-file <build.file>] [-c / --settings-file <settings.file>]`. And when you run it, those specified `<build.file>` and `<settings.file>` will be used to configure the build and it's settings correspondingly. Settings file is special: it configures your [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/ProjectDescriptor.html) objects on the very early stages of your build and it can actually [override](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/ProjectDescriptor.html#setBuildFileName(java.lang.String)) it's build file.

Here are the examples (sorry for the deprecated `<<`, it is used just to shorten the code):

**Default `build.gradle`, no `settings.gradle`**:

`build.gradle`:

```
task hello << { println "Hello" }
```

Results:

```
$ ./gradlew hello
:hello
Hello
```

**Custom `build.gradle`, no `settings.gradle`**:

`custom.gradle`:

```
task hello << { println "Hi!" }
```

Results:

```
$ ./gradlew -b custom.gradle hello
:hello
Hi!
```

**Custom `build.gradle`, configured in `settings.gradle`**:

`custom.gradle`:

```
task hello << { println "Konnichi wa" }
```

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.buildFileName = 'custom.gradle'
```

Results:

```
./gradlew hello # note that we don't need any flags here as with a default build
:hello
Konnichi wa
```

**Custom `build.gradle`, configured in custom `settings.gradle`**:

`custom.gradle`:

```
task hello << { println "Aloha!" }
```

`settings.custom`:

```
rootProject.buildFileName = 'custom.gradle'
```

Results:

```
./gradlew -c settings.custom hello # note how we pass custom settings file which, in turn, specifies custom `build.gradle`
:hello
Aloha!
```

That is all mostly fancy and not practical, but you can combine these approaches to store, for example, all you build files in one separate directory (overriding `buildFileName`). Or you can have something like "build profiles" with multiple `settings.gradle`, with different set of `include`s (settings are also used to include projects into you build, so you can have profiles like "full build", "ui", "external clients" and so on).

The only limit is your imagination.

Comment: Amazing comments. A combination between a build and setting file is very helpful to custom shell script (CI/CD). Appreciate your comment a lot

Answer (score 4):

In this case `build.gradle` is read under the same directory where you run `gradlew`. Other file that may also be read is `settings.gradle` but tasks cannot be declared there.

To run different gradle script use `-b` switch and pass the path to the script.

Also, why do you suppose that any other file might be read?

Comment: I was thinking maybe it went through all .gradle files and read them, but that clears it up, thank you!

Comment: Please note, this is only correct when running Gradle with the `-u` / `--no-search-upward` option. Without this option, Gradle will search parent directories for `settings.gradle` files for multi-project configuration.